# Lua string.len, string.lower or any other string function not working

Tags: string, lua

I am using Lua (5.2.1), in a library, called from C++.

For example from C++ I call the function OnHear and pass the heard text.

In my Lua files, however, I have examined something weird:

```
function OnHear(_Text)
    txt = _Text;
    txt = string.lower(txt); -- comment this line to make the code below run
-- other code
end
```

It does not work; "other code" runs fine when the line with lower is commented, but not if it is being executed.

```
function OnHear(_Text)
    txt = string.lower(_Text);
-- other code 
end
```

same problem...

I also found out, that the same problem (code afterwards not being executed) occurs when I call for instance string.len(txt) or anything like that...

I have no idea what could cause my problem and Googling/searching Stackkoverflow did not help me, sadly...

Thanks for any reply in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you opened the Lua standard libraries from C++?

> ```
> void luaL_openlibs (lua_State *L);
> ```
>
> Opens all standard Lua libraries into the given state.

From http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_openlibs.

**EDIT**

The `lua` binary opens the libraries by default, but sometimes, when the
interpreter is embedded, the libraries can be superfluous.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the problem :) I did not know about this function yet...(I feel dumb^^)